# what is setUp and tearDown in PHPUnit Test?

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

What is use of setUp() and tearDown() both methods in the PHPUnit. Its invoked automatically in the test class? when it is work and how to call this two methods?

Answer (score 2):

The method `setUp()` will be called before each one of the test method and `tearDown()` method will be called after every test method has been executed. Suppose you want to test two table's data. So for that you have to always need a connection and after execute your query you have to close the connection. So instead of every time we create and close connection for each method, we can do something like this

```
protected void setUp() {
//code for getting connection
}
protected void tearDown() {
//code for close your connection
}

void testAccoountTable() {
//test code for account table
}
void testEmployeeTable() {
//test code for Employee table
}
```

Now when you run the tests `testAccountTable` and `testEmployeeTable` the `setUp` (before execution of every test method) and `tearDown`(after execution of every test method) method will be automatically called for every test method.

Comment: Basically the concept is same. If you have any particular code for every method that you want to execute before and after every test method then you use `setUp()` and `tearDown()` method. I like to know about in your case how it's actually work?

Comment: thanks for reply... you mean manually call setUp and tearDown in each method (if required). I am right?

Comment: @Kumar If you run all the tests, setUp() and tearDown() will called automatically for every test method.

Comment: what you mean by "run all the tests". i can't.. will you please explain little bit.. i am really new for this concept..

Comment: In the above example there is two tests. If you run two of them, then the setUp() and tearDown() will called for each test method. Means first setUp() then -> testAccountTable() then ->tearDown() will be called. Then again setUp() -> testEmployeeTable() then -> tearDown() will be called. You have to just write once setUp() and tearDown() and they will automatically called for every test method. @Kumar

Comment: OK fine.. i need to know.. have to config before to start phpunit test in my project

Comment: first of all i'll explain where i am in my project... my project is based on web service using php. already developer done the project.. my role is implement the phpunit test for this web project... so i start to learn... but i don't know which is right way to implement php unit test..

Comment: You can go through some documentation. Here is the link https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html   And if you find this post helpful you can mark this as a right answer. @Kumar

Comment: what is purpose of testsuites like the following code '<phpunit>
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="money">
      <directory>tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
</phpunit>'

Comment: Kindly go through the previous link which is provided in the comment. Then if you have any query, post another question. This can't be explain in the comment..

Comment: Note that in recent PHPUnit versions, `setUp` and `tearDown` need to be declared [`void`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58393351/6243352).