# php fatal error Declaration of UserTest setUp function

Tags: php, phpunit, fatal-error

I had to do a PHPUnit testing with setUp function given below:

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class UserTest extends TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
       var_dump('1');
    }
}
```

When I run this test it shows me these errors:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of UserTest::setUp() must be compatible with PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::setUp(): void
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Try ´protected function setUp(): void´ instead of your declaration of setUp() - as documented, really. See https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.3/fixtures.html

Comment: Thanks, @jasie . It works and I already solved it. Check my answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to declare the return type of template methods such as `setUp()` to be `:void`. This is explained [here](https://phpunit.de/announcements/phpunit-8.html) and [here](https://thephp.cc/news/2019/02/help-my-tests-stopped-working#return-type-of-template-methods).

Comment: What if your unit test addresses PHP 7.0 through to 8.0?

Comment: Then do not use `setUp()` and `tearDown()` but instead name your methods differently and annotate them with `@before` and `@after`, respectively.

Comment: Great advice! You know so much about phpunit!

Answer (score 9):

I fixed this error with a quick time by using void method like given below:

```
 public function setUp(): void
 {
    var_dump('1');
 }
```